# Why am I not getting the correct random number if I take input from html input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following function SHOULD generate a random number between the range of max and min. And it does, when I pass numbers directly in the argument.

```
function randomIntFromRange(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

However when I take input from HTML form, it doesn't generate random value between max and min, rather it generates a random value between 0 and max-min.

Am I doing some obvious stupid mistake? Please help.

```js
var num = 100;

function randomIntFromRange(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function trial() {
  num = randomIntFromRange(document.getElementById("a1").value, document.getElementById("a2").value)
  console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" type="text" value="100">
<input id="a2" type="text" value="150">
<button onclick="trial()">click</button>
```

Comment: Please include the required code to demonstrate the problem _in the question itself_. You can use the stack snippet functionality (see [mcve]) - also your code produces `NaN` not what you think it does.

Comment: @Jamiec sorry, i had uploaded the wrong fiddle. I have corrected the fiddle now. Can you check again? It was my first experience with jsfiddle so apology for the inconvenience

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get the value from the input using `.value` and then convert it into a number either using

```
+document.getElementById("a1").value
```

or

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").value)
```

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

**Syntax**

```
parseInt(string)
parseInt(string, radix)  // You can use 10 as a radix to parse it into decimal
```

I've created a `button`, By clicking on it `trial` function will get called.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

var num = 100;

function randomIntFromRange(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function trial() {
  num = randomIntFromRange(+document.getElementById("a1").value, +document.getElementById("a2").value);
  console.log(num);
}

button.addEventListener("click", trial);
```

```html
<input id="a1" type="text" value="100">
<input id="a2" type="text" value="150">
<button>get result</button>
```

Comment: If using `parseInt` please remember the radix argument - I think we can assume the user wanted base-10 `parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").value,10)`

Answer (score 1):

The function works... But this

```
document.getElementById("a1")
```

Gives you element but you need its value, which is string... You need to convert the string to an integer (same with "a2"):

```
Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").value)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the input value to number

```js
parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").value)
```

another way is to use `number()` instead of `parseInt()`